# Invalid Object Name #temp_Table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, temp-tables, sapb1

When I try to execute this code :

```
insert into myTable
    select col1, col2 
    from #temp_Table
```

I got this error:

> Invalid Object Name #temp_Table

I am writing this code in SAP Business one as a SQL query and the temp table itself is defined already in the same query.

When I only run

```
select col1, col2  
from #temp_Table
```

it works fine. Only as `insert into`  does not.

Any suggestion what the problem could be?

Comment: Show the whole query

Comment: The problem is obvious.  `#temp_table` is not defined.  You might need a global temp table (`##temp_table`), but that might introduce other issues.

Comment: It is a very simple Query where i define a temp_Table with some Data and then try to insert them into a Table .. As I said , whithout insert into the Query works fine and show me col1,col2 perfectly.Now i only need to add them to a Table and this doesnt work!

Comment: But why should it be a problem using a temp_Table while inserting Date into a table ?

Comment: are you running both query in same query window? Otherwise I am not getting any problem with your query.

Comment: Can you please share the whole query?